# How to add a shared legend for 9 plots grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am new with ggplot2 and I am trying to plot 9 different plots in one and I want to add a common legend.

Here you can see the pearsons correlations that I want to plot:

```
PEARSONSCORRELATIONS_MOD1
 [1] 0.10470688 0.10827255 0.12322448 0.11887717 0.12719741 0.12635607 0.13427974
 [8] 0.13539245 0.13636687 0.13834174 0.13864013 0.13816236 0.13640052 0.13775515
[15] 0.13563827 0.13968726 0.12499506 0.11836173 0.11097081 0.09829338 0.10470688
```

*They are different for each model (let me know if needed all of them).

Here is the code for the plot:

z <- 1:21

```
 PLOTPEARSON_MOD1 <-ggplot (data=df_MOD1, mapping= aes (x=z, y=PEARSONSCORRELATIONS_MOD1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(col="black")+
  scale_x_continuous(name="", breaks=z, labels=PEARSONSCORRELATIONS2)+
  geom_point(col="black", shape=42,size=7, aes(11, PEARSON30_MOD1))+
  theme_light()+
  scale_y_continuous(name="",limits = c(-.1, 1), breaks=seq(-.1,1, by= .1 ))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, size=5))+
  ggtitle ("Model 1")
```

Note that I have added a single point with geom_point.

And here is the code that I have used to put the nine plots in one:

```
grid.arrange (arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD1)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD4)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD7)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD2)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD5)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD8)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD3)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD6)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD9)
              , ncol=3,nrow=3,top="Title")
```

But I am stuck. I want to add a common legend for this plot. I have tried with "shared legend" but I am not even able to put a simple legend for each plot. It is a black and white plot and I just need to show this:

*(shape=42)="text"
Circles (default shape)= "Text"

Is there any way to add a simple legend? or how can I add a legend to each plot?

Hope that I have explained this properly. It is one of my first posts here.

Thank you so much in advance.

With all good wishes,

Answer (score 2):

The reason no legend is being shown for shape and color is that you haven't mapped shape and color to any variable--you've only set them to constant values. A legend is only created when the aesthetic feature (size/color/shape/linetype/etc) is mapped to some variable. Otherwise, ggplot2 assumes it's a just a design element. If the shape is intended to map a variable, you need to map the shape parameter in `aes()` just like you have the `x` and `y` parameters.

Take a look at this example. Here, I have added a "group" variable to the data frame for the plot, then mapped this variable to `shape` inside of `aes()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  index = 1:21,
  corr = c(0.10470688, 0.10827255, 0.12322448, 0.11887717, 0.12719741, 0.12635607, 0.13427974,
           0.13539245, 0.13636687, 0.13834174, 0.13864013, 0.13816236, 0.13640052, 0.13775515,
           0.13563827, 0.13968726, 0.12499506, 0.11836173, 0.11097081, 0.09829338, 0.10470688),
  group = c(rep("Group A", 14), rep("Group B", 7))
)

p1 <- ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = index, y = corr, shape = group) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  theme_light()
p1
```

[image]

After you have mapped the variable, you can manually choose the shapes to use with `scale_shape_manual()`:

```r
# specify specific shapes, see http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/
p2 <- ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = index, y = corr, shape = group) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  theme_light() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17))
p2
```

[image]

For arranging the plots in a grid, I strongly recommend the [patchwork package](http://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) instead of `grid.arrange()`. It is a more modern package that is much easier to work with and also does a nicer job of aligning the axes, etc. With patchwork, you can just `+` the plots together. You can control the number of rows/columns with `plot_layout()`. You also use that function to tell it to collect all of the guides (legends) that are the same across plots into a combined legend for the whole patchwork. You can see other options at the package website.

```r
library(patchwork)
p1 + p1 + p1 + p1 + p1 + p1 + p1 + p1 + p1 +
  plot_layout(ncol = 3, nrow = 3, guides = "collect")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

(One final thing: When you post a question, it's best to post complete code that anyone could copy and paste to run without needing to modify. I did that in my examples above. This is called a "reproducible example". In the code you posted, your code doesn't load any libraries and includes object names like `PEARSONSCORRELATIONS2` that you haven't defined in the code, so I needed to edit your code before I could run it. The `reprex::reprex()` function makes it really easy to make a reproducible example that you can paste onto a page like this.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpfull answer. I need now add labels as I have posted in this thread. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your helpful answer.

I will always use the full code now.

It works perfectly and now I am trying to put the nine plots in one using patchwork as you suggested me to do.

I have managed to make it work but I cannot add labels for each plot. I had done that with grid.arrange() as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(lattice)

t <- textGrob("Proportion of S1>S2 on Variable1")

lay <- rbind(c(1,2,3),
             c(1,2,3),
             c(1,2,3),
             c(1,2,3),
             c(1,2,3),
             c(1,2,3),
             c(1,2,3),
             c(4,4,4),
             c(5,6,7),
             c(5,6,7),
             c(5,6,7),
             c(5,6,7),
             c(5,6,7),
             c(5,6,7),
             c(5,6,7),
             c(8,8,8),
             c(9,10,11),
             c(9,10,11),
             c(9,10,11),
             c(9,10,11),
             c(9,10,11),
             c(9,10,11),
             c(9,10,11),
              c(12,12,12))

grid.arrange (arrangeGrobPLOTPEARSON_MOD1, top="High w", left="High p correlation")
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD4,top="Medium w correlation")
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD7,top="Low w correlation")
              ,arrangeGrob(t)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD2, left="Medium p correlation")
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD5)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD8)
              ,t
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD3, left="Low p correlation")
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD6)
              ,arrangeGrob(PLOTPEARSON_MOD9)
              ,t
              , ncol=3,nrow=24,top="Title", layout_matrix=lay)
```

Is there any way to add labels for each plot and subset of plots?

Thank you so much again.

With all good wishes,

Comment: Either add a title to each plot with `labs()` or add tags to the patchwork with `plot_annotation(tag_levels = "a")`.